# Python Multiprocessing using *args

Tags: python, multiprocessing, variadic-functions

I am creating a python process in the following way

```
def make_process(p_num, *args):    
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
                        target=process_func, args=(args, p_num,))
```

The problem is that `args` is being passed to `process_func` as a tuple but I want to expand the tuple elements as a normal arguments.  I tried `args=(*args, p_num,)` but this created a syntax error.  Is there a way to expand the arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add tuples.

```
args=args + (pnum,)
```